# Iterate over IEnumerable stops after first iteration

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have the following in my `Main()` method

```
Reeks r = new Reeks();

foreach(int i in r){
    if(i < 1000){
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

What i want is to iterate over a `Reeks` until the value of `i > 1000` where `i` is the previous value multiplied by 2, ie `[1,2,4,8,16,32]`.

The class `Reeks` looks like this

```
class Reeks : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerator<int>
{
    private List<int> reeks;
    private int idx = -1;

    public Reeks()
    {
        reeks = new List<int>() {1};
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (idx < reeks.Count - 1)
        {
            idx++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        idx = -1;
    }

    public int Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (idx == -1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration has not started. Call MoveNext");
            }
            else
            {
                if (idx != 0)
                {
                    reeks.Add((reeks[(idx-1)]*2));
                }
                return reeks[idx];
            }
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it stops iterating after the first iteration, it just print the `1` at the beginning and not the values that should come after that.

Comment: `if (idx < reeks.Count - 1)` fails in `MoveNext`. Is this a homework and you need to implement an iterator by hand? Otherwise you can easily use iterator blocks.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it unfortunately is

Comment: Adding into list in Current is extremely dangerous and should not be done. Do it in MoveNext instead!!!

Comment: you are implementing this stuff for homework? Wow - most useless homework I've ever seen - this is only applicable to .net/C# and there it's outdated (sorry it's OT but I am really wondering why you would want your students to know this stuff instead of getting a good feeling for more general concepts of programming)

Comment: @CarstenKönig I don't agree. It could be a good excercise to figure out how iterators work. Knowing how something works tends to be better than just assuming it does what it does.

Comment: @CarstenKönig We had Java the first year where we hade the more general concepts, this is in depth on .net

Comment: as a more constructive comment: you should not both implement `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` in the same class - better split it into two

Comment: @DionV. then better *reinvent*  the interfaces and let the students play with it - then it would not matter which OOP environment they are using and they would get a even better understanding. Not everything in .net is pure CS-gold - anyhow: it is really **OT** so I'll stop here - as I said: I was just wondering why you would want to teach this stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need a `List<T>` there. `if (idx < reeks.Count - 1)` in `MoveNext` fails in second iteration.

If it isn't necessary to implement your custom iterator, I'd do it with iterator blocks.

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Reeks()
{
    int num = 1;
    yield return num;

    while (true)
    {
        num = num * 2;
        yield return num;
    }
}
```

Then use it as

```
foreach (int i in Reeks().TakeWhile(x => x < 1000))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

As you said in comments this has to be a custom iterator. Hand written iterator blocks would look something like this. Note the `List<T>` removed, you don't need a list. You just need to know what is the last value returned.

```
class Reeks : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerator<int>
{
    private int current;
    private int idx = -1;

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (idx == -1)
        {
            idx = 0;
            current = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current * 2;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        idx = -1;
    }

    public int Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (idx == -1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration has not started. Call MoveNext");

            return current;
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's an easy one. Your `List` has only one element. When iterating over `Reeks` (and thus, calling `MoveNext()`) you increment your `idx` by 1. Still fine.

However, your `MoveNext()` is defined as

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
    if (idx < reeks.Count - 1)
    {
        idx++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Let's iterate over the first two;

**Iteration 1**

```
idx = -1;
reeks.Count = 1; //Because reeks is a List containing 1 element

if(-1 < 0)
{
    idx++;
    return true;
}
```

Which works.

**Iteration 2**

```
idx = 0; //incremented -1 by 1
reeks.Count = 1; //Not altered

if(0 < 0)
{
    //Not reached!
}

return false;
```

Which will return false.

**Edit**

The answer provided by Sriram is probably the best and most elegant. If you, however, have to stick with the code you currently have, you can indeed add a the next element in your `MoveNext()` method. This will also make it infinite.

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
    int size = reeks.Count - 1;
    if (idx < size)
    {
        idx++;
        reeks.Add(reeks[size]*2);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix? Do I have to add the next element in the list when `MoveNext` is called? because it should be an infinite series of `int`'s